# How to duplicate html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

A part of my webpage duplicates the same code 24 times with slightly different variables. It looks like this:

```
<div id="timeTable" class="container timeTable expand ">

    <div class="row tableData">
            <div style="width: 13%; " class="col-xs-1 <?php checkColor(1); ?>">01 AM</div>
            <div style="width: 37%;" class="col-xs-5 center <?php checkColor(1); ?>">
                <p id="hour1" class="hName"></p>
                <input id="1" class="short hidden hInput" type="text">
            </div>

            <div style="width: 13%;" class="col-xs-1 <?php checkColor(13); ?>">01 PM</div>
            <div style="width: 37%;" class="col-xs-5 center <?php checkColor(13); ?>">
                <p id="hour13" class="hName"></p>
                <input id="13" class="short hidden hInput" type="text">
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row tableData">
                <div style="width: 13%;" class="col-xs-1 <?php checkColor(2); ?>">02 AM</div>
                <div style="width: 37%;" class="col-xs-5 center <?php checkColor(2); ?>">
                    <p id="hour2" class="hName"></p>
                    <input id="2" class="short hidden hInput" type="text">
                </div>

                <div style="width: 13%;" class="col-xs-1 <?php checkColor(14); ?>">02 PM</div>
                <div style="width: 37%;" class="col-xs-5 center <?php checkColor(14); ?>">
                    <p id="hour14" class="hName"></p>
                    <input id="14" class="short hidden hInput" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row tableData">
                <div style="width: 13%;" class="col-xs-1 <?php checkColor(3); ?>">03 AM</div>
                <div style="width: 37%;" class="col-xs-5 center <?php checkColor(3); ?>">
                    <p id="hour3" class="hName"></p>
                    <input id="3" class="short hidden hInput" type="text">
                </div>

                <div style="width: 13%;" class="col-xs-1 <?php checkColor(15); ?>">03 PM</div>
                <div style="width: 37%;" class="col-xs-5 center <?php checkColor(15); ?>">
                    <p id="hour15" class="hName"> </p>
                    <input id="15" class="short hidden hInput" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
```

All I really need is a javascript while loop and then something that can write the code in to my document... something like:

```
A = 1, B = 13. While A => 12, B => 24, A++, B++. 
<div class="row tableData">
        <div style="width: 13%; " class="col-xs-1 <?php checkColor(1); ?>">01 AM</div>
        <div style="width: 37%;" class="col-xs-5 center <?php checkColor(1); ?>">
            <p id="hourA" class="hName"></p>
            <input id="A" class="short hidden hInput" type="text">
        </div>

        <div style="width: 13%;" class="col-xs-1 <?php checkColor(13); ?>">01 PM</div>
        <div style="width: 37%;" class="col-xs-5 center <?php checkColor(13); ?>">
            <p id="hourB" class="hName"></p>
            <input id="B" class="short hidden hInput" type="text">
        </div>
        </div>
```

Can someone please show me code examples? Thank you!

Comment: Where is your script ? On which event you want to manipulate the `DOM` ?

Comment: Why you are not doing this on server side, as checkColor is php function you need to repeat this template at server side only, then n then you can use that function.... otherwise you need to implement that function at client side aswell

Comment: @Benjamin: is it okay to use php?

Answer (score 0):

what you are describing is a template,
checkout ractivejs 
http://www.ractivejs.org/

just make a simple look that will go over an array of variables with the same template

Answer (score 0):

Here how Ractive probably does its job:

```js
var placeholder = /\{\{(\w+)\}\}/g;
var productEl = document.getElementById("product");
var productTpl = compile(productEl.text);

productEl.parentNode.innerHTML = [
  { name: "Rubber Duck", price: "cheap", color: color },
  { name: "Gold Duck", price: "expensive", color: color }
].map(productTpl).join("");

function color () {
  switch (this.price) {
    case "cheap": return "orange";
    case "expensive": return "red";
    default: return "black";
  }
}

function compile (tpl) {
  tpl = tpl.replace(/\n/g, "");
  tpl = tpl.replace(/"/g, "\\\"");
  tpl = "return \"" + tpl + "\";";
  return new Function("data", tpl.replace(placeholder, "\"+("
  + "typeof data.$1 == \"function\" ? data.$1() : data.$1"
  + ")+\""));
}
```

```css
body{text-align:left}table{border-collapse:collapse}td,th{border:1px solid black;padding:.25em}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="products">
    <script id="product" type="text/plain">
      <tr>
        <td>{{name}}</td>
        <td style="color:{{color}}">{{price}}</td>
      </tr>
    </script>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

"compile" takes a string and returns a function:

```
var tpl = compile("<b>{{text}}</b>");
// tpl = function (data) {
//   return "<b>" + (typeof data.text == "function" ? data.text() : data.text) + "</b>";
// }
tpl({ text: "ping" }); // "<b>ping</b>"
tpl({ text: "pong" }); // "<b>pong</b>"
```